# Emacs reference cards from my wall to emacs

Tags: emacs, texinfo

I've become very reliant on some of the emacs [reference cards](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/refcards/) - so much that I sometimes have to get up from my laptop and go to the room where my printed copies are hanging on the wall.

Is there an easy way to get the reference shown in emacs in textinfo format or something similar?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but if you are using Emacs then ***ask Emacs***.  That's my unsolicited advice. Learn to use `C-h m`, `C-h b`, `C-h k`, `C-h f`, and `C-h r`.  The last of these puts you in the Emacs manual, where you can use `i` followed by typing some text and hitting `TAB` to look something up in the index (`TAB` completes the text you type).  IOW, break loose of relying on a reference card. ;-)

Comment: They are all very useful command and probably better is the long run than the cheat sheet but for example earlier today I was looking for the a way to insert an entire file in a buffer (what proved to be C-x i). I was pretty clueless about what emacs would call such a function so the cheat sheet came in handy ...

Comment: (OK bad example, just checked and the function is called `insert-file` which is fairly descriptive ...)

Comment: For command, other-function, user-option, other-variable names, and more, the `apropos` family of commands is helpful.  You never know what order the parts of a name are in. Several of these commands are already bound to keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of the reference card (`refcard.tex`) ships with the Emacs source, in the [./etc/refcards](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/etc/refcards) directory. [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) provides options to convert from .tex to .texinfo, as explained in this answer from [tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34996/how-can-i-convert-a-tex-document-to-texinfo-format).